# Why can't I classify my data perfectly on this simple problem using a NN?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have a set of observations made of 10 features, each of these features being a real number in the interval (0,2). Say I wanted to train a simple neural network to classify whether the average of those features is above or below 1.0.

Unless I'm missing something, it should be enough with a two-layer network with one neuron on each layer. The activation functions would be a linear one (i.e. no activation function) on the first layer and a sigmoid on the output layer. An example of a NN with this architecture that would work is one that calculates the average on the first layer (i.e. all weights = 0.1 and bias=0) and asseses whether that is above or below 1.0 in the second layer (i.e. weight = 1.0 and bias = -1.0).

When I implement this using TensorFlow (see code below), I obviously get a very high accuracy quite quickly, but never get to 100% accuracy... I would like some help to understand conceptually why this is the case. I don't see why the backppropagation algorithm does not reach a set of optimal weights (may be this is related with the loss function I'm using, which has local minmums?). Also I would like to know whether a 100% accuracy is achievable if I use different activations and/or loss function.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

X = [np.random.random(10)*2.0 for _ in range(10000)]
X = np.array(X)
y = X.mean(axis=1) >= 1.0
y = y.astype('int')

train_ratio = 0.8
train_len = int(X.shape[0]*0.8)
X_train, X_test = X[:train_len,:], X[train_len:,:]
y_train, y_test = y[:train_len], y[train_len:]

def create_classifier(lr = 0.001):
  classifier = tf.keras.Sequential()
  classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1))
  classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))#, input_shape=input_shape))
  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)
  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()],
  classifier.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False), metrics=metrics)  
  return classifier

classifier = create_classifier(lr = 0.1)
history = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=1000, validation_split=0.1, epochs=2000)
```

[image]

Comment: Your model is actually a simple logistic regression, and not a neural network proper.

Comment: Agree, but the question would still apply. Say that for some reason I want to implement it as a NN using Keras and TF, why don't I get full convergence?

Comment: Your rationale is faulty: implementing a logistic regression (LR) with TF or Keras does *not* make it a NN; it is still a (simple) LR. Only difference with, say, LR in scikit-learn, is that here it is trained using SGD, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that a neural network is an odd approach for this problem, and answering your specific question - it looks like your learning rate might be too high which could explain the fluctuations around the optimal point.

Comment: That makes sense, so obvious and still hadn't thought about it. When using a lr = 1x10e-5 and enough iterations, I get much closer to 100%. Still interesting that it does not manage to classify all the points correctly, since that wouldn't require to reach the exact optimum I think (just close enough so that all the test examples fall on the correct side).

Comment: You could gradually decrease the learning rate, so that it coverges to the minimum but don't forget that with gradient descent you rarely reach the minimum point itself. I'm guessing that the examples which the model is still mistaken about are the ones whose average is very close to 1 (the tipping point).

Comment: If my answer helped you, it would be great if you could 'accept' my answer :D